# Best practice of adding node(s) to elasticsearch cluster

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm using `Zen Discovery` module to connect all nodes together, but when I want to add a new node to the cluster, I have to change every node's `discovery.zen.ping.unicast` config to add the new node's ip, and then restart all nodes.

When the cluster's nodes grow up to a big number, it's impossible to do this manually, what should I do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do not have to change every node's configuration, especially not restart every node.

You only have to add one or more running nodes into the new node's `discovery.zen.ping.unicast`. That is enough for the new node to discover and join the cluster.

Comment: In theory, if you have dedicated master nodes, they should be the ones you list on data nodes. The masters would all have each other listed.